# Spring autoconfigurations, @ConditionalOnBean with a @Repository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-repositories

I have a starter module which expose a marker interface along with some repository:

```kotlin
interface AwesomeRepo

...

internal interface FakeRepository: Repository<JPAStub, String>, AwesomeRepo {
    fun count(): Long
}

@Entity
class JPAStub(@Id val name: String)
```

```kotlin
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@ConditionalOnBean(EntityManagerFactory::class)
@AutoConfigureAfter(JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration::class)
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = [FakeRepository::class])
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = [FakeRepository::class])
class AwesomePersistenceAutoConfiguration
```

In another module, I have an auto configuration which depends on the `AwesomeRepo` to instantiate the `AwesomeApplicationService`

```kotlin
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
class AwesomeAutoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    @ConditionalOnBean(AwesomeRepo::class)
    fun awesomeAppService(awesomeRepo: AwesomeRepo) =
            AwesomeApplicationService(awesomeRepo)
```

I import both autoconfigure starters in a root project.

I observe:

- `AwesomeApplicationService` cannot be instantiated because `AwesomeRepo` bean cannot be found

*When enabling debug through `debug=true`:*

```
AwesomeAutoConfiguration #awesomeAppService:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnBean (types: *****.AwesomeRepo; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans of type *******.AwesomeRepo(OnBeanCondition)
```

- I tried adding `@AutoConfigureOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)` to `AwesomePersistenceAutoConfiguration` and `@AutoConfigureOrder(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)` to `AwesomeAutoConfiguration`. It did not change the issue
- When I remove the `@ConditionOnBean(AwesomeRepo::class)`, the `AwesomeApplicationService` is correctly instantiated with the repository and everything is fine.

Why does the `@ConditionOnBean(AwesomeRepo::class)` does not detect the `AwesomeRepo` bean?

EDIT: After more trials and errors, it seems order was causing the issue, applying accepted answer worked. If someone needs to go further there is a baseline of code illustrating the issue here: https://github.com/Nimamoh/spring-autoconfigurations-conditionalonbean-with-a-repository (accepted answer is on `snic-answer` branch)

Comment: You have working solution. What is your question?

Comment: Edited the post, I wonder why the `ConditionOnBean` does not detect the `AwesomeRepo` bean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AwesomeAutoConfiguration` should be ordered after `AwesomePersistenceAutoConfiguration` so that the bean definitions for the repositories are processed before the condition kicks in.

There is a note in `@ConditionalOnBean` about this specifically:

> The condition can only match the bean definitions that have been processed by the application context so far and, as such, it is strongly recommended to use this condition on auto-configuration classes only. If a candidate bean may be created by another auto-configuration, make sure that the one using this condition runs after.

You can use `@AutoConfigureAfter(AwesomePersistenceAutoConfiguration.class)` on `AwesomeAutoConfiguration` to order things properly.